# Nested expandable listview in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have implemented expandable listview using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/):

But my requirement is to create a nested expandable listview.
Something like this:

```
Movies
  Hollywood
    Coming Soon
      abc1
      abc2
      abc3
    Now Showing
      abc1
      abc2
      abc3
  Bollywood
    Coming Soon
      abc1
        vcvc
        vcvc
        (..many more levels)
      abc2
      abc3
    Now Showing
      abc1
      abc2
      abc3
```

If someone has implemented this before, please share.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/shahbazhashmi/nested-expandable-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, but I don't know its proper or not.

At first, use `TextView` for headers like Hollywood, Bollywood, Coming Soon, and for others too excepts in last second nested list. Use `ExpandableListView` for last second nested list. In your case-

```
Movies    //Tv
  Hollywood    //Tv
    Coming Soon  //  --
      abc1       //   |
      abc2       //   |
      abc3       //   |  ExpandableLV
    Now Showing  //   |
      abc1       //   |
      abc2       //   |
      abc3       //  --
  Bollywood    //Tv
    Coming Soon    //Tv     
      abc1    //Tv          
        vcvc    //Tv
        vcvc                  //    -
                              //     |  ExpandableLV
        (..many more levels)  //    - 
      abc2    //Tv
      abc3    //Tv
    Now Showing // -
      abc1      //  |
      abc2      //  |  ExpandableLV
      abc3      // -
```

Now you would wonder how stupid is this. You want to give the whole list expandable effect. So that's why I got a solution for it too.

Use `Visibility` feature for all `Textview`s. Whenever any particular `Textview`'s `OnClickListener` listener is called, toggle `Visibility` of inner data.

E.g. In your case - when `Movies` is clicked, call `HollywoodTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and `BollywoodTextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. And then when `HollywoodTextview` is clicked, call `HollywoodComingSoonNowShowingExpandableLV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. Similarly, keep toggling as required. I hope this helps.

Note: you might come across a scrolling problem bacause of manual scrollbars you would use and inbuilt scrolls of `ExpandableListView`. See if you can tackle it. Pleasure!

Answer (score -1):

```
out_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:progress="50"
                android:progressTint="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Progress"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>  

Java
```